# Synonymize tags related to partitioning

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I discovered recently that apart from the well-known tag [partitioning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/partitioning) (10,271 questions currently), there is also the tag [partitions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/partitions) with 771 questions.

Even funnier thing is that the tag [partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/partition) is a synonym to [partitioning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/partitioning), leaving [partitions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/partitions) unrelated.

Shouldn’t [partitions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/partitions) be a synonym of [partitioning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/partitioning)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My request is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) now, thank you Oli!

Answer (score 9):

I agree. Some even have both; seems overkill to me.

And it is 767 :=)

Comment: 766 now… Someone must have started to remove the tag manaully.

Comment: I did the few on the fp I saw ;-)

Comment: And done now.  (Thanks Oli)